# Mapping IP address to local Webserver

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, webserver

im currently lost as to why i can't properly map my website.. here is the situation..

my website is currently hosted on a local webserver running as Guest OS on Virtual Box. im running a CentOS 6.5.. now, here is the details for that OS,

CentOS
     IP Addr = 192.168.0.102

my HTTPD.CONF on CentOS

```
Listen *:80

  NameVirtualHost *:80

  <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin root@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/public
      ServerName laravel.localhost.com
     ServerAlias laravel.localhost.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/html/logs/erro_log
     CustomLog /var/www/html/logs/access_log common
  </VirtualHost>
```

my /etc/hosts

```
   127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
   127.0.0.1 laravel.localhost.com
   192.168.0.102 laravel.localhost.com
   laravel.localhost.com               192,168.0.102
   ::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

now for my Host OS, which is running on win7, and when i access my website @ laravel.locahost.com.. it can't seem to find my site.. but when i access through 192.168.0.102.. it goes directly to my site.. what seems to be the problem here? can anyone point it out to me.. im already oout of ideas and been googline it for some time.. all of them give me the same workaround but my problem still persist..

=== UPDATE ====

here is my updated /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1               localhost laravel.localhost.com
192.168.0.102           localhost laravel.localhost.com
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 laravel.localhost.com
192.168.0.102 laravel.localhost.com
laravel.localhost.com 192,168.0.102
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

Remove the 4th line. I think the comma (,) in the IP address is causing the problem. And another thing is that hosts file should be in the format

```
<ip-address> <hostname> <alias> ...
```

and not

```
<hostname> <ip-address>
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Edit:
You need to add this line

```
192.168.0.102           localhost laravel.localhost.com
```

to your host machine's hosts file i.e. Windows 7 hosts file

Comment: hmmm okay update my /etc/hosts file.. please see my updates.. and still problem persists.. whenever i access this url http://localhost.laravel.com/ it can't find my site

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think you didn't map your local domain in your host OS's hosts file.

Comment: do i need to restart my host machine??.. it seems that i still can't access localhost.laravel.com

Comment: If I'm not wrong, then I think it was laravel.localhost.com

Comment: ohhh man.. wait wait gonna fix my naming.. got it messed up.. will feedback u in a bit..

Comment: Yes yes, it worked, sorry about the cofusion on the naming.. got so mixed up with all the edits and configs ive done.. tnx anyway man